# File not readable exception - pear/Config_Lite

Tags: php, config, pear, ini

I have two config files located in: `/etc/svnauth` and `var/www/svnauth`

I have given read, write access to for both files like shown below

```
chown -R apache:apache /etc/svnauth
chmod -R 770 /etc/svnauth

chown -R apache:apache /var/www/svnauth
chmod -R 770 /var/www/svnauth
```

When I try to read these two files using pear/Config_Lite, `/etc/svnauth` always fails. I can successfully read the `/var/www/svnauth` file

Any reasons for this? What am I missing here

Following is the error message i get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Config_Lite_Exception_Runtime' with message 'file not readable: /etc/svnauth' in /var/www/html/svnmanager/Config/Lite.php:112 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/svnmanager/index.php(60): Config_Lite->read('/etc/svnauth') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/svnmanager/Config/Lite.php on line 112
```

Answer (score 0):

is open_basedir set in your php.ini? If so, does it contain /etc/?

Comment: I don't think so,  it looks like this `; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
;open_basedir =
`